# unknown look-behind group near index in Java

Tags: java, regex

Here's a minimalist sample of the code that is failing:

```
String al = "(?<xyz>chicago)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(al, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

I am getting a:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown look-behind group near index 13
(?<xyz>chicago)
             ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2505)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:1806)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1752)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1460)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1133)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:847)
         :
         :
```

What am I missing/overlooking? I am working on Eclipse with java 1.7.

Comment: What did you intend to do?

Comment: FYI, for some unknown reason, when I try a named capture in RegexBuddy, it wants to add the UNICODE_CASE flag. Would you try this, just in case, and sees if the problem goes away? Java regex is super buggy! lol `Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<xyz>Chicago)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);` Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this exception using Java 1.7 or 1.8.  That regex compiles fine on both platforms.

It has been pointed out to me (by @zx81) that `(?<xyz>...)` is the Java regex syntax for named group capture.  So I checked the Javadoc, and:

- the syntax is supported in Java 1.8
- the syntax is supported in Java 1.7
- the syntax is *not* supported in Java 1.6.

So my theory is that you are *actually* executing your code with a Java 1.6 (or earlier) JRE, and that is treating this an unknown kind of look-behind.

Comment: So, I not only had to add the JRE 1.7 in Eclipse's preferences, but since my computer initially had 1.6 when I created the project, I also needed to remove the JRE libraries on the build path and replace them with 1.7

Comment: Actually, it is the runtime classpath that matters.  You probably changed both paths ...

Answer (score 0):

answer from compiler indicates that regex syntax is invalid:

- `(?P<name>regex)` - is syntax for named groups
- `(?<=regex) / (?<!regex)` is positive/negative look-behind

if unescaped, both '(' and '?' are special characters and don't make any sense together so non-arbitrary continuation required, like

- `(?i)` -- case-insensitive match
- `(?s)` -- single-line mode
- `(?:regex)` -- non-capturing group, etc